# Pointer Function

Tags: c++, function, pointers

Can someone explain what this actually represents ?

```
Foo *getfoo()
{
    return foo_object;
}
```

`Foo` here is a class. 
My question is what does the pointer before the function name represents?

Comment: `Foo*` is the return type. You'd better consider the function signature as `(Foo*) getfoo` not `Foo (*getfoo)`.

Comment: @neuront: You cannot put parentheses around the return type, it invalidates the declaration. `Foo* foo()`, `Foo *foo()` and `Foo (*foo())` are all equivalent (even if the last is a little misleading); `(Foo *)foo()` is a call to `foo` with a cast on the return type.

Comment: @CharlesBailey You are right. That's not legal in grammar, which I write is just to help understanding the syntax structure of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others noted, 'Foo *' syntax means function is returning a pointer to a place in the memory, not an object itself.

It has the implications that, if you get this pointer, this means getfoo() could've allocated memory for it. Thus it's possible you will have to free it yourself, otherwise this memory will be allocated for the whole time your program is running. This is called a memory leak.

Here is an example with freeing memory:

```
class Foo {};

Foo *getfoo() {
  Foo *f = new Foo();  // Memory allocated here
  return f;
}

int main () {
  Foo *g = getfoo();
  // some code here

  delete(g); // free the memory as "g" is no longer needed.

  return 0;
}
```

In C++ it's crucial that you learn to manage memory. Otherwise, sooner or later, your apps will fail. There are some programming patterns helping with that, of which the most popular is [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).

Answer (score 1):

Some people like to add the asterisk right before the name. I personally prefer this syntax:

```
Foo * getfoo () {
  return foo_object;
}
```

I think that shows a bit more clearly that `Foo *` is just the type the function returns (just like it could be `int`).

Answer (score 1):

It means that the function returns a pointer.
and what `type` that pointer is what is mentioned before the pointer.
that is the pointer will be of type `Foo`.`Foo` here is as you said is a `class` and **the function returns a class object pointer**.

Answer (score 0):

getfoo functions returns a an object pointer(of class foo)